# 2011 Lexus RX replace with smaller-than-OEM-dimension battery

Tags: battery

My vehicle is 2011 Lexus RX, and I replaced the new battery at [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B000MS9VZK/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o05_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000MS9VZK). The new battery dimension is smaller than the OEM battery.

Attempt to fix this problem, I bought a new battery hold down at [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00FDXIK3I/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00FDXIK3I). The problem is that this new hold-down has "J" hinge on both sides.

My original OEM has one side attached to the interior car frame, and a "J" hinge on the other side. I don't see my engine bay has another hole for the another "J" for the new batter hold down.

What's your take on this?

Comment: Relate parts are here: https://parts.lexus.com/p/Lexus_2011_RX-350/CLAMP/63449940/7448126020.html

Answer (score 1):

Make a spacer for the original hold down - wood or plastic is a good idea but metal is not.

Or, get the correct size battery. Some cars are very temperamental about the battery voltage...

Comment: Can I just use electrical tape to make the spacer? To stack electrical tape layer by layer?

Comment: If you have to ask, you won’t listen.